# Qt QHeaderView::sectionResized and QHeaderView::geometriesChanged not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt 5.7, and I have a `QWidgetTable` that starts off with no rows. When I insert the first row, the width of the table's verticalHeader (which has type `QHeaderView`) changes from 0 to 15. Yet neither signal is fired.

Perhaps `sectionResized` means that the user has resized the section with the mouse, but shouldn't `geometriesChanged` definitely be fired?

I need this because I want the `QWidgetTable` to resize its width correctly to the contents. But if I call the resize function manually immediately after inserting or deleting a row, the `width()` member function of the verticalHeader returns the old value. For example, it returns 0 immediately after inserting the first row even though it should be 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at Qt source code, geometriesChanged only fired in these cases:

```
case QEvent::FontChange:
case QEvent::StyleChange:
        d->invalidateCachedSizeHint();
        Q_FALLTHROUGH();
case QEvent::Hide:
case QEvent::Show: {
        ....
            resizeSections();
        emit geometriesChanged();
        break;}
```

Comment: That would explain what I am seeing. So is this a defect in the library?

Comment: Maybe there is an alternative way to do what you are trying achieve?

Comment: I edited the question to explain what I am trying to achieve. I did find an alternative way, but it is not elegant at all. A bit of a kludge actually...

Comment: Maybe resizeColumnsToContents() after insertion?

Comment: No, I want the column size fixed. For example, if the text doesn't fit in one of the columns then the text should wrap.